# Regular expression to match start of filename and filename extension

Tags: python, sql, regex, sql-like

What is the regular expression to match strings (in this case, file names) that start with 'Run' and have a filename extension of '.py'?

The regular expression should match any of the following:

```
RunFoo.py
RunBar.py
Run42.py
```

It should not match:

```
myRunFoo.py
RunBar.py1
Run42.txt
```

The SQL equivalent of what I am looking for is `... LIKE 'Run%.py' ...`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

For a regular expression, you would use:

```
re.match(r'Run.*\.py$')
```

A quick explanation:

- . means match any character.
- * means match any repetition of the previous character (hence .* means any sequence of chars)
- \ is an escape to escape the explicit dot
- $ indicates "end of the string", so we don't match "Run_foo.py.txt"

However, for this task, you're probably better off using simple string methods. ie.

```
filename.startswith("Run") and filename.endswith(".py")
```

Note: if you want case insensitivity (ie. matching "run.PY" as well as "Run.py", use the re.I option to the regular expression, or convert to a specific case (eg filename.lower()) before using string methods.

Comment: 1. you don't have to specify start of line for python regular expression match?
2. * is zero or more match (i.e. so Run.py would be acceptable)

Comment: Also, how would you make it case-insensitive?

Comment: re.match already specifies the start of the string (as opposed to re.search, which doesn't).  "Run.py" *should* match, given the definition (It starts with Run, and has a .py extension).  For case insensitivity, see the note at the end.

Answer (score 18):

I don't really understand why you're after a regular expression to solve this 'problem'. You're just after a way to find all .py files that start with 'Run'. So this is a simple solution that will work, without resorting to compiling an running a regular expression:

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir(dirname):
    root, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if root.startswith('Run') and ext == '.py':
        print filename
```

Comment: What is the year 2024 version of this snippet?

Answer (score 15):

Warning:

- jobscry's answer ("^Run.?.py$") is incorrect (will not match "Run123.py", for example).
- orlandu63's answer ("/^Run[\w]*?.py$/") will not match "RunFoo.Bar.py".

(I don't have enough reputation to comment, sorry.)

Answer (score 10):

```
/^Run.*\.py$/
```

Or, in python specifically:

```
import re
re.match(r"^Run.*\.py$", stringtocheck)
```

This will match "Runfoobar.py", but not "runfoobar.PY". To make it case insensitive, instead use:

```
re.match(r"^Run.*\.py$", stringtocheck, re.I)
```

Comment: Your complete example helped me.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need a regular expression, you can use glob, which takes wildcards e.g. Run*.py

For example, to get those files in your current directory...

```
import os, glob
files = glob.glob( "".join([ os.getcwd(), "\\Run*.py"]) )
```

Answer (score 4):

If you write a slightly more complex regular expression, you can get an extra feature: extract the bit between "Run" and ".py":

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = '^Run(?P<name>.*)\.py$'
>>> m = re.match(regex, 'RunFoo.py')
>>> m.group('name')
'Foo'
```

(the extra bit is the parentheses and everything between them, except for '.*' which is as in Rob Howard's answer)

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't fully comply with file-naming standards, but here it goes:

```
/^Run[\w]*?\.py$/
```

Comment: looks like a Perl solution for a question tagged python... but I am not a python expert :p and as jobscry pointed out your solution is case-sensitive.

Comment: Shouldn't you use .*, rather than \w - punctuation and whitespace etc should probably still be considered part of the filename. eg "Run.foo.py"

Answer (score 0):

mabye:

```
^Run.*\.py$
```

just a quick try