# Trying to create a Python Script to extract data from .log files

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to create a Python Script but I'm a bit stuck and can't find what I'm looking for on a Google search as it's quite specific.

I need to run a script on two **.log** files (auth.log and access.log) to view the following information:

> **Find how many attempts were made with the bin account**

*So how many attempts the bin account made to try and get into the server*.

The logs are based off being hacked and needing to identify how and who is responsible.

Would anyone be able to give me some help in how I go about doing this? I can provide more information if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I've managed to print all the times 'bin' appears in the log which is one way of doing it. Does anyone know if I can **count** how many times 'bin' appears as well?

```
with open("auth.log") as f:
for line in f:
    if "bin" in line:
        print line
```

Comment: Or you can simply using cat file.log | grep "keywords"

Comment: What about this: `cat file.log | egrep "keyword1|keyword2|..." | wc -l` (the egrep gives you the possibility to search for keyword1 OR keyword2 and the "wc -l" gives you the opportunity to count.

Comment: I've edited the original post with how I've done it, any suggestions if there's a way to count those occurrences?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you work with system logs and their format is known and stable, my approach would be something like:

- identify a set of keywords (either common, or one per log)
- for each log, iterate line by line
- once keywords match, add the relevant information from each line in e.g. a dictionary

You could use shell tools (like `grep`, `cut` and/or `awk`) to pre-process the log and extract relevant lines from the log (I assume you only need e.g. error entries).

You can use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16017858/515948) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If you want ot use tool then you can use ELK(Elastic,Logstash and kibana).
if no then you have to read first log file then apply regex according to your requirment.

Answer (score 0):

In case you might be interested in extracting some data and save it to a `.txt` file, the following sample code might be helpful:

```
import re
import sys
import os.path


expDate = '2018-11-27'
expTime = '11-21-09'


infile = r"/home/xenial/Datasets/CIVIT/Nov_27/rover/NMND17420010S_"+expDate+"_"+expTime+".LOG"

keep_phrases = ["FINESTEERING"]

with open(infile) as f:
    f = f.readlines()

with open('/home/xenial/Datasets/CIVIT/Nov_27/rover/GPS_'+expDate+'_'+expTime+'.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write("gpsWeek,gpsSOW\n")
    for line in f:
        for phrase in keep_phrases:
            if phrase in line:
                resFind = re.findall('\.*?FINESTEERING,(\d+).*?,(\d+\.\d*)',line)[0]
                gpsWeek = re.findall('\.*?FINESTEERING,(\d+)',line)[0]
                gpsWeekStr = str(gpsWeek)

                gpsSOW = re.findall('\.*?FINESTEERING,'+ gpsWeekStr + ',(\d+\.\d*)',line)[0]
                gpsSOWStr = str(gpsSOW)

                file.write(gpsWeekStr+','+gpsSOWStr+'\n')
                break

print ("------------------------------------")
```

In my case, FINESTEERING was an interesting keyword in my `.log` file to extract numbers, including GPS_Week and GPS_Seconds_of_Weeks. You may modify this code to suit your own application.